# SharePoint Server broken membership with DC and doesnt have a local admin password. What to be done?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, active-directory, domain, membership

In one of our QA farms, we restored the old VM snaps and one of the server couldn't able to connect to the FARM due to the broken membership with DC and we unfortunately dont have the local admin password.

What to be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

i think at this time you have to rebuild the server and then add into the farm.
I am sure you know VM snapshot not recommended for recovery.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/08/24/virtual-machine-snapshots-for-sharepoint/